# AnyEvent Fork::Pool vs Worker::Pool

Tags: perl, anyevent

**Background**

I need to write a program which launches, monitors and reports the status of upto a few thousands of shell scripts.

I find two modules in the AnyEvent space (AnyEvent::Fork::Pool and AnyEvent::Worker::Pool) which seem to do the work

The description is not sufficient for me to understand which is more suitable for my purpose.

Initial attempts to install AnyEvent::Worker::Pool resulted in a failure (same failure observed at CPAN Tester http://cpantesters.org/cpan/report/10f80e0e-eea4-11e6-9f92-baad96342c9b )

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a difference target audience for the two modules or are they two separate implementation for the same job(TIMTOWTDI)
2. What is the difference between the two modules?
3. Is AnyEvent::Worker::Pool suffering from bitrot (Last update nearly 7 years back)

Comment: I haven't answer to your questions because I always use [Poe::Wheel::Spawner](https://metacpan.org/pod/Poe::Wheel::Spawner)